# Vuex getter gives typeerror "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to make a check if a form field is pristine or not. I do this from the getter in Vuex and not from the component (which I need to keep clean from logic). Somehow it gives the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value).city is not a function

getters.js

```js
citySelected(state) {
  const city = state.inputs.filter(item => item.name === 'city')[0].pristine;
  if (city) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
},
```

actions.js

```js
if (!getters.citySelected(state)) {
  return;
}
```

I expect it to turn back true or false. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong in this instance?

Comment: There is no promise shown and `city` isn't being used as a function, so this code isn't enough for debugging.  If this is called from an action, show it and show how you call it

Comment: in the action i just have only this logic
  if (!getters.citySelected(state)) {
    return;
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getters aren't called like functions:

```js
myaction({ getters }) {
  if (!getters.city) { return; }
}
```

(Unless it's a method-style getter, but this one is not.)